# What does the overline symbol mean?

Tags: notation, fourier-analysis

So I have got a question in an old exam paper for Fourier Analysis.

Let $f:I\to C$ be an integrable function. Prove that$\int_I   \overline{f(x)}= \overline{\int_I  f(x)}$. The problem is that I don't know what does the overline of a function means here. Can someone help?

Comment: Complex conjugation.

Comment: It is the composition of $f$ with complex conjugation. For example, if $f(z)=z^2+1$, then $\overline{f(z)} = \overline{z}^2+1$ (apply $f$, then conjugation).

Comment: $\overline{x+iy} = x - iy$ where $x,y$ are real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex conjugation, that is
$\overline{x+yi}=x-yi$. With $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about *whistles innocently* :) Thanks for pointing it out